# When would MutableList.add() ever return false?

Tags: android, kotlin

This [Android Kotlin basics tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-lists?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-lists#2) about lists says:

> The add() function returns true if adding the element to the list
> succeeded, false otherwise

But on practice it seems the add() method either returns true when it succeeds or throws an exception if you try to pass an invalid parameter.

In what situation would the add() method return false? Could anyone give me an example?

Comment: in the documentation said "@return `true` because the list is always modified as the result of this operation." so i understand that always is true and is not possible a false value

Comment: With every mutable collection there is the possibility that one runs out of memory.

Comment: @ManuelMato you're right, you should submit as an answer, just found that at https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html

Comment: @lukas.j wouldn't that just throw an exception tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the documentation said "@return true because the list is always modified as the result of this operation." so i understand that always is true and is not possible a false value

Answer (score 2):

The `add` function of a `MutableList` is inherited from the `MutableCollection` interface, which is why it must return a `Boolean`. The documentation for [`MutableCollection.add`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-collection/add.html) says this:

> Return `true` if the element has been added, `false` if the collection does not support duplicates and the element is already contained in the collection.

Lists always support duplicates, which is why the documentation for [`MutableList.add`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html) specifies that this method always returns `true`. However, there are other types of collection, such as sets, that don't. When you try to add an item to a set, it will return `false` if the item was already in the set.

Comment: But why this method defined in super class in list instead of set interface i think that would be better it could behave differently in super class (collection) can you explain?